# Trie implementation runtime error

Tags: c++, pointers, trie

I'm trying to implement a Trie in C++ but I'm getting runtime error...

Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct trie{
    bool word = false;
    trie* adj [26];
    trie(){}

    void add(char* s){
        trie* t = this;

        while(s){
            if(t->adj[s[0] - 'a'] == NULL){
                trie nova = create(s);
                t->adj[s[0] - 'a'] = &nova;
                return;
            }
            else{
                t = t->adj[s[0] - 'a'];
            }
            s++;
        }
    }

    trie create(char* s){
        trie t;
        trie* point = &t;
        while(s){
            point->adj[s[0] - 'a'] = new trie();
            point = point->adj[s[0] - 'a'];
            s++;
        }
        point->word = true;
        return t;
    }

    void seek(){
        trie* t = this;
        run(t, "");
    }

    void run(trie* t, string s){
        if(t->word){
            cout<<s<<"\n";
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
            if(t->adj[i] != NULL){
                run(t->adj[i], s + char('a' + i));
            }
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    trie t;
    t.add("ball");
    t.add("balloon");
    t.add("cluster");
    t.seek();
}
```

It works like that:

- suppose I'm adding a word;
- if the letter of the word isn't in the trie

  ```
   if(t->adj[s[0] - 'a'] == NULL)
  ```

  - make new trie with void create and set t->adj[s[0] - 'a'] to that new trie
- else just go to the next letter and repeat the proccess

  ```
   t = t->adj[s[0] - 'a'];
  ```

What am I doing wrong? I'm *new* at using pointers and I think I must have used one (or more) of them mistakenly... What is it wrong?

Comment: I'm running it on codeblocks, when it starts, 1 second later it says the program stopped working...

Comment: This needs to be part of your question. Please [edit] to include details. See also [ask]

Comment: (It's helpful that you included your code, but it's too much for someone to simply glance at and understand what the problem is, without any explanation.)

Comment: Have you tried stepping with a Debugger?

Comment: Also, don't do that: `using namespace std;` And why don't you use the `std::string` instead of char. I see that you are already using it in `void run`

Comment: I'm using string just to print, I'm trying to learn pointers.. I have explained the code a little bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems which was found in your code.

1. One problem resides in stack local variable `trie nova` being being deleted when it goes out of scope.

Code

```
...
if(t->adj[s[0] - 'a'] == NULL){
    trie nova = create(s);
    t->adj[s[0] - 'a'] = &nova; // address points to memory on stack
    return;
} // nova is deleted. t->adj[s[0] - 'a'] is pointing to trash now.
...
```

To handle it you should work with pointers and `new` operator.

```
...
if(t->adj[s[0] - 'a'] == NULL){
    trie* novaPtr = create(s + 1);
    t->adj[s[0] - 'a'] = novaPtr; 
    return;
} 
...

trie* create(char* s){
    trie *t = new trie();
    trie* point = t;
    while(*s){
        point->adj[s[0] - 'a'] = new trie(); // allocate memory on heap
        point = point->adj[s[0] - 'a'];
        s++;
    }
    point->word = true;
    return t; // the pointer on heap memeroy is returned.
}
```

---

2. As @bkVnet noticed, you also should check for string termination in while loops all over the place. `while(*s)` - meaning while `s` is not pointing to `'\0'` symbol instead of `while(s)`.

---

3. You should initialize your `adj` pointers with *NULL* in struct constructor. Then it would be correct to check them for being *NULL* int he line `if(t->adj[s[0] - 'a'] == NULL)`.

Construct code.

```
trie() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) adj[i] = NULL;
}
```

---

4. There is a logical error in the line `create(s);` as one character should be taken away - `create(s + 1)`.

[**Full working code example**](https://ideone.com/XpL5nb)

Comment: You are right, but it's not called coruption. Corupted memory happens when you overwrite the memory thinking it's something else. What the code does is that that it keeps a pointer to a variable past it's end of life (the `nova` is deleted when it goes out of scope).

Comment: Also *while(s)* is just checking for the character pointers for NULL, i believe the intent is to check for the null terminator character in the string which should be *while(*s)*.

Comment: @bkVnet, You are right. Another issue which should be mentioned.

Comment: I made the changes but it still didn't work (runtime problem), i debugged after the additions but they are not working, only the first one and its kind of bugged

Comment: @Daniel, see edits. Found another issues. You'd better learn to debug your code.